# How to use pdp11 simulator with Unix V7

Tags: boot, download

I got a pdp11 simulator here http://www.jbox.dk/sanos/pdp11.htm that contain the Unix V7 Operating System. I wanna use it so as there described I did all necessary things and burn it using [ISO to USB](http://www.isotousb.com/) ([Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) was unable to burn it) but after booting to the bootable drive I'm gotting an error it shows that "Any operating system wasn't found". Whatr should I do to use it?
Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The provided Sanos image can’t boot directly from a USB key, it only supports booting as a CD.

The simplest way to try it out is to boot the CD image in an emulator; for example, using QEMU on Fedora:

```
qemu-kvm -cdrom pdp11.iso
```

Comment: Uh is there any emulator for Windows 10?

Comment: Yes, you could use Virtual Box.

Comment: Uh can you please explain me why it doesn't run from a USB drive but runs from a CD? What's the difference between running from a USB drive and a CD drive? Please explain it to me!